# Yii :: Mulitilanguage issues

Tags: yii, multilingual

I am developing a project in Yii multi language and i done setting up the language files , now i need to fetch english message if any translation is missing in current language file.
my file structure is :

-> protected

```
 -> messages

    ->en -> main.php

    ->nl -> main.php etc...
```

Comment: did you check this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n ?

Comment: Yes i did it and it worked for English and Dutch. In dutch some text are missing for that i need to take English translation. That is what am checking now.

Comment: I think an event will be triggered on missing translation, search for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Add this in your config/main.php in components array.

```
'messages' => array(
        'onMissingTranslation' => array('MessageHelper', 'textMissingTranslation'),
    ),
```

Create a file MessageHelper.php in components and add the below code in it

```
class MessageHelper
{
  public static function textMissingTranslation($event)
   {
     $var = include( Yii::getPathOfAlias( 'application.messages.en.main').'.php' );        
     return $event->message = $var[$event->message];
  }
}
```